# What's the fastest way to convert a string of text into a url-safe variable?

Tags: python, string

I'd like to convert a string of text, e.g., "User Name" into something which I can turn into part of a url, e.g., "User-Name."  What's the fastest way to do a string replacement ("-" for " ") as well as make sure that characters are only [a-zA-Z0-9]?

Comment: Why do you need the fastest way? I find it extremely unlikely that URL encoding can be the bottleneck of any application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string.translate is often the fastest solution for these sorts of problems (assuming your strings aren't unicode).

```
def translate(x):
    if x == ' ': return '-'
    if 'a' <= x <= 'z': return x
    if 'A' <= x <= 'Z': return x
    if '0' <= x <= '9': return x

def mk_translator():
    translations = ''.join(translate(chr(c)) or chr(c) for c in xrange(256))
    deletions = ''.join(chr(c) for c in xrange(256) if translate(chr(c)) is None)
    return translations, deletions

def urlize(x, translator=mk_translator()):
    return x.translate(*translator)

print urlize('User Name')
```

Comment: I removed my answer since it will allow letters, digits and characters.

Answer (score 1):

[urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) won't turn spaces to dashes, but to %20, but its designed exactly for the purpose of making string url-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function for that purpose:

```
import unicodedata

def slugify(item):
    ret = item.lower().replace(u' ', u'_')

    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', ret).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

I'm not sure if it's the fastest way, though.

Answer (score 0):

I like Ofri's version for simplicity and safety, and user97370's version for making spaces look nice.

Why not have both?

I would do it like this:

```
import string, urllib
trans = string.maketrans(' ', '-')
x = 'a sentence with a bunch of spaces'
x2 = x.translate(trans)
x3 = urllib.quote(x2)
print x3 #--> 'a-sentence-with-a-bunch-of-spaces'
```

In other words, do one method and then the other. `x3` should be safe to use in url string. You don't need to make new parameters for each, could just keep recreating `x`, i used `x2` and `x3` to make it clearer. You could also add other things in the translation matrix, if there are things other than spaces you want to get rid of.